# Flutter two ListViews side-by-side with overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I tried to figure this out today and didn't find an answer, that worked like I hoped.

I want to create a Page with two ListViews in a Row (or other Component) side-by-side where one is flex: 3 and the other is flex:1.
But in my case I get an overflow error. Is there something I missed?

[image: That's the layout I want to create.]

Any tips? 
I tried a OverflowBox but that doesn't really work. And I didn't find a setting to hide the overflow like in CSS.

```
Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: MovementList(),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: OverflowBox(
                        child: MovementList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: When you make one of them flex 3 and other flex 1 you declare first one size will be triple of second so second one just doesn't fit the area that's why you get error. If you want to make same size your lists you should make flex 1 for each. If you want to reach second list with swipe screen then you should put both listview under another one which will be scrobble horizontal. Can't say much without seeing your code.

Comment: Yeah I want the look of flex:3 and flex:1. And on swipe I want to change the one to flex:1 and the other to flex:3.

Comment: You can use both Expanded if you want to achieve no overflows but make sure to add dimensions to its parents widget, you dont need flexible